# Removing Drywall around Windows

Tags: drywall, windows

I am removing all of the drywall in my bathroom due to old age and some damage over time. I have removed most of the drywall but have come to this point and I am a little unsure what to do. I have looked online for some demos or videos on what to do around this area but have come up short.

I know I have to remove the trim to get to the drywall behind, but do I have to remove the window sill or the window itself to get to the rest along the insides of the window enclosure itself? And help would be appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Why would you not leave that area undisturbed? I see no damage that warrants replacement.

Comment: Because everything is else in the bathroom is being gutted so the assumption is to just start fresh with everything. Also there was water damage on the right side of the window shown and taking off that drywall would allow me to make sure nothing else near the window has rotted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I am doing demo work I usually pull the trim, if the cill is in good shape I might not remove it unless changing the look like going from painted to stained wood finish.

Comment: I agree, but we can't tell much about the trim from the photo provided. I'd offer more advice if I could see better.

Comment: Just to clarify. Once I remove the trim, I should have no problem removing the drywall around the windows correct?

Comment: Yes there is usually a small gap right of the edge.